# Moving tabs should reset stack in react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

say I have a two tab application:

```
a1 > a2
b1
```

Where if I click on an item on a1, I go to a2, and a video autoplays. Now when I click b1, I want this video to stop playing (so this page should be popped from the stack).

```
<Scene key="Home" backToInitial={true}>
    <Scene key="Home" component={Home} title="Home" initial={true}/>
    <Scene key="Video" component={Video} title="Video" />
</Scene>
<Scene key="Submit" backToInitial={true}>
    <Scene key="Submit" component={Submit} title="Submit" />
</Scene>
```

the `backToInitial` seems to work on the home tab, where if I click the home tab while the video is playing on a2, it pops the scene from stack and the video stops playing. I see on the github forums that this should work:

```
<Scene key='TABSCENE' type={ActionConst.RESET}/>
```

But when I add that `type` to my Submit scene, nothing happens. This should reset my entire router right? Where exactly am I supposed to put this code so that when I change tabs the video stops playing? Thanks!